# Width property 100% for flex items (.destination img) inside flex box (#destinations) is not applied, white space doesn't get removed, What's wrong?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, frontend

My problem lies in highlights section, a ul flexbox #destinations and flexitems .destination.

I want each flex-item (`.destination`) to take a third of flexbox width so that white space is removed, and images are the same size. But applying `width: 100%`doesn't change anything as it logically should:

picture of output [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI6EH.jpg)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
}


/* header */

#page-logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Oleo Script", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(245, 243, 160);
  font-size: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(245, 243, 160);
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

nav a:hover {
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  background-color: rgb(255, 251, 0);
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#hero {
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/BZkCP2Hk/ocean.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 800px;
}

#hero-container {
  width: 900px;
  background-color: rgba(51, 47, 47, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px rgb(68, 67, 67);
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}

#hero-container h1 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

#hero-container p {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

#hero-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(255, 251, 0);
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px rgb(68, 67, 67);
}

#hero-container a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0);
}


/* highlights section */

#destinations {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.destination img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@700&family=Oleo+Script:wght@700&family=Quicksand:wght@300;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

<header>
  <!-- logo -->
  <div id="page-logo">
    <a href="index.html">Travel Goals</a>
  </div>

  <!-- nav -->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="Places.html">Destinations</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <section id="hero">
    <div id="hero-container">
      <h1>Jo's Travel Page</h1>
      <p>Lets Explore The World Toghether!</p>
      <a href="/Places.html">Discover Places</a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- highlights section -->
  <section id="highlights">
    <h2>Highlights</h2>

    <!-- image container flex box -->
    <ul id="destinations">
      <!-- flex items -->
      <li class="destination">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tJZtmgQB/miami.jpg" alt="pic of miami" />
        <p>Miami <strong>USA</strong></p>
      </li>
      <li class="destination">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Jzq6XG1X/munich.jpg" alt="pic of munich" />
        <p>munich <strong>Germany</strong></p>
      </li>
      <li class="destination">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/DycdjHtk/barcelona.jpg" alt="pic of barcelona" />
        <p>barcelona <strong>Spain</strong></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>

<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to improve the readability of your first paragraph, in which you seem to be trying to describe your problem? I've edited your question to convert your posted code to a runnable snippet, does that snippet reproduce your problem? If no, please edit it so that it does. You may need to add images into that code that we can see, there are many place-holder image sites on the internet to which you should be able to link.

Comment: thanks a lot for making my question clean i didnt know how to make snipets here. i made changes and added img files now if you run it it will duplicate the problem. third image (.destination) being smaller in width

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule:

```
.destination {
  flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
}
```

Your flex items are not the images (`.destination img`), but the `.destination` divs, so you need to prevent them from growing or shrinking and define their width, all with the above rule.

Aditionally, the fixed height of 200px for the images will cause them to be displayed distorted on smaller screens - you have to come up with another solution for this...

BTW: For `#hero-container` I would replace `width: 900px` with `max-width: 900px` to make sure it doesn't overflow smaller screens.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
}


/* header */

#page-logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Oleo Script", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(245, 243, 160);
  font-size: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(245, 243, 160);
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

nav a:hover {
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  background-color: rgb(255, 251, 0);
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#hero {
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/BZkCP2Hk/ocean.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 800px;
}

#hero-container {
  max-width: 900px;
  background-color: rgba(51, 47, 47, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px rgb(68, 67, 67);
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}

#hero-container h1 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

#hero-container p {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

#hero-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(255, 251, 0);
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px rgb(68, 67, 67);
}

#hero-container a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0);
}


/* highlights section */

#destinations {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.destination {
  flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
 }
.destination img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@700&family=Oleo+Script:wght@700&family=Quicksand:wght@300;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

<header>
  <!-- logo -->
  <div id="page-logo">
    <a href="index.html">Travel Goals</a>
  </div>

  <!-- nav -->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="Places.html">Destinations</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <section id="hero">
    <div id="hero-container">
      <h1>Jo's Travel Page</h1>
      <p>Lets Explore The World Toghether!</p>
      <a href="/Places.html">Discover Places</a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- highlights section -->
  <section id="highlights">
    <h2>Highlights</h2>

    <!-- image container flex box -->
    <ul id="destinations">
      <!-- flex items -->
      <li class="destination">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tJZtmgQB/miami.jpg" alt="pic of miami" />
        <p>Miami <strong>USA</strong></p>
      </li>
      <li class="destination">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Jzq6XG1X/munich.jpg" alt="pic of munich" />
        <p>munich <strong>Germany</strong></p>
      </li>
      <li class="destination">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/DycdjHtk/barcelona.jpg" alt="pic of barcelona" />
        <p>barcelona <strong>Spain</strong></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>

<footer></footer>
```

Comment: thats irrelevant i want the flex box to have 90% width for section and it does it. the problem is i want each of li items (.destination) inside the flex box(#destinations) to take 100% of flex width which would be 33% for all and all should be same width. the width value dosent apply and .destination width stays the same

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you before, okay. Please see my edited/changed answer, including explanation.

Comment: @Johannes This gives a terrible transformation af the pic's on small width

Comment: @Johannes the logic of my code is right and width should work im asking why it dosent. my flex containers are not divs but li elements. (.destination) now each li element when in a flexbox gets its width by its contents required width. so if each one of images inside .destination gets 100% width available and bcs there are 3 flex-items inside a flexbox each one should get one third of total width and therefore be same width whit ohters. but as you see width:100% dosent apply for some reason

Comment: @Kken Because the images are NOT the flex items (i.e. the *direct* children of the flex container). The flex items are the `.destination` DIVs, the images are *children* of the flex items, so rules that should apply to the flex items need to have `.destination` as  a selector, like in my answer.

Comment: i did actually try giving .destination itself a width of 100%. didnt make any changes to li size. im following udemys course and in video the guy writes the exact same code and when applies width 100% white space gets removed and each li gets third of width

Comment: If you say you want 100% width for each flex item, do you mean you want them to be *above*  each other?  In this case, you need to use `flex-direction: column` on the flex container (`#destinations`)

Comment: @Michel That's due to the 200px fixed height on the images. Of course this would have to be removed to preserve the proportions of each image, but that's not really part of the question (which concerns the width)

Comment: The problem is the fixed height if the images. Your images are 1200 * 800 px, so a fixed height of 200px will always give a width of 300 px, even if the container has more room. Change it to `height: auto; width 100%` and it works

Comment: @Johannes no. look at code snippet results. i want them to be in a row as they are. but width of each .container to be same as others. right now if you look at them whit chrome dev tools you see that each image and li has diffrent width and third image is more noticable

Comment: @Kken Your code is obviously **not** correct, otherwise it would work. So if someone is trying to help you, don't say: my code is right, your's not.

Comment: @  
Michel i checked it 5 times and as i mentioned its exactly the same code instructor on udemy writes and runs. if my code is not correct you can point out where not just saying its not correct whitout any reason

Comment: @Kken If you look at *my*  snippet using the dev tools, each image has a width of 185.4px - they are all the same width, so what you say is not correct. BTW, @ Michel is right about the height problem, but that's a different issue.

Comment: @Johannes Combined all issues are solved.

Comment: i wanted it to be done whit width, as i mentioned in udemys design course it works whit same code. it can be done whit appling specific width to third image but i was just wondering why it didnt work. thanks for your time anyway ill skip this and move to next lesson for now